# Codeigniter site_url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Начал осваивать codeigniter по туториалу, подскажите в чем проблема, код вьюхи:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a>
```

Генерирую url для ссылки, он получается верный, функция site_url как и положено ей возвратит sitename.ru/index.php/news/slug1. В ссылке же, href равен sitename.ru/index.php/sitename.ru/index.php/news/slug1. Само собой такого роута у меня нет

Comment: модреврайт возможно корректирует, не?

Comment: вообще я точно по туториалу все делал, htaccess не трогал, реврайта там нет

Comment: попробуйте слеш убрать у "news/"

Comment: вот кстати похожая тема http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998525/code-igniter-relative-urls-stop-working-when-url-ends-in-slash

Comment: Не помогает, будет тоже самое только без слеша newsslug1

Comment: Да, кажется то что нужно, спасибо за ссылку

Comment: <a href="//<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a> ?

Comment: В ссылке реальн такой href - при просмотре исходника страницы? Или вы просто забыли слеш поставить, и браузер считает урл относительно текущей страницы (и показывает кривой урл при ховере поверх ссылки)?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы функция `site_url()` работала корректно, нужно задать бэйс_урл в конфиг файле `application/config/config.php`

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://твой-хост/';`

Там же, чуть ниже, можно выкинуть index.php из УРЛа:

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Я site_url не использую пишу просто

```
<a href="news/<?= $news_item['slug']; ?>">View article</a>
```